# How to disable browser back button after logout in jhipster project

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I am using a jhipster Gateway project. I have created custom screens and when i tried to logout and then clicked the browser back button, its navigating to the previous screens. How to prevent this ?

One of my state.js file:

(function() {
    'use strict';

```
angular
    .module('wheelsoncloudgatewayApp')
    .config(stateConfig);

stateConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

function stateConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('tenantRegistration', {
        parent: 'dashboard',
        url: '/tenantRegistration',
        data: {
            authorities: []
        },
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/tenantRegistration/tenantRegistration.html',
                controller: 'TenantRegistrationController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }

    });
    $stateProvider.state('tenantView', {
        parent: 'dashboard',
        url: '/tenantDetails',
        data: {
            authorities: []
        },
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/tenantRegistration/tenant.html',
                controller: 'TenantRegistrationController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }

        }

    });
    $stateProvider.state('tenantUserView', {
        parent: 'dashboard',
        url: '/userDetails/:id',
        data: {
            authorities: []
        },
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/tenantRegistration/userDetail.html',
                controller: 'TenantRegistrationController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }

    });

}
```

})();

Comment: Protect your route/state by authorities so that user cannot navigate to them.

Comment: Sorry, my actual question is, need to prevent browser back button after logout. With the default jhipster gateway project, when i logout, and then click the browser back button, its taking to signin page. (This is what i want). But, after adding my custom screens, this feature is not working. I think i missed something, Please help me on this

Comment: Is your "login/logout" state stored somewhere?

Comment: No, there are no separate state for that

Comment: @GaëlMarziou, is restricting state, would prevent browser back button after logout ?

Comment: So how do you know the user is loged in with an active session while using your application?

Comment: Based on the token, we can identify about login. After logout, token will be deleted from session and local storage

Comment: yes if you put `authorities: ['ROLE_USER']` it will prevent anonymous user (after logout) to reach tenantView state. See doc at http://www.jhipster.tech/using-angularjs/

Comment: Thankyou so much @GaëlMarziou.. It worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protect your states by setting `authorities: ['ROLE_USER']` it will prevent anonymous user (after logout) to reach tenantView state. See doc at http://www.jhipster.tech/using-angularjs/